# Why is the rest of my code is being ignored after I only have sent the first input?

Tags: c, file, scanf, fgetc

I'm trying to write a program that asks for input of the name of a file and a char to be counted inside the file. But whenever I input the proper name of a file (like, "file.txt") it jumps right to the end of the program with a output like this:

"Name of the file: file.txt
Character to be counted:
The char occurs 0 times in the file "

...but I couldn't even type the char to be counted.
I know it's not an issue with the name of the file, because if I put the wrong name, it goes for the output I programmed for.
Would anyone care to explain me what's happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(void) {
  char filename[128];
  printf("Name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s", filename);


  FILE * test = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (test == NULL) {
    printf("Error!!\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char inpt;

  printf("Character to be counted:\n");
  scanf("%c", &inpt); //gets the character to be counted

  int count = 0;

  char search = fgetc(test);

  while(search != EOF) {
    if (search == inpt) count++;
    search = fgetc(test);
  }

  printf("The char occurs %d times in the file\n", count);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: always test the return of `scanf()`. And consider what typed and left to be read (and you did not), like the `ENTER` that terminated the 1st `scanf()`... The `ENTER` is feeding the next `scanf`, where you also did not test the return

Comment: `scanf("%c", &inpt);` -> `scanf(" %c", &inpt);`. The space before `%c` will absorb the `\n` which is still in the input stream.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. So, how do I take the enter out of the input stream?

Comment: @Jonas read my previous comment closely

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for not realizing before.